# confusion with encryption

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that generates a list with the numbers from 1 to 26 in random order, then 'encrypts' a given word using that list so that the n'th letter of the alphabet is mapped to the n'th number in the randomized list. Example:

the randomized list is:

```
[8,2,25,17,6,9,12,19,21,20,18,3,15,1,11,0,23,14,4,7,24,5,10,13,16,22]
```

which means that the word `act` becomes `[8,25,7]` and the word `xyzzy` becomes `[13,16,22,22,16]`.

I have the following code, but I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
#8a
def randomalpha():
    a=[0]*26
    count = 0
    while count < 25:
        r = randrange(0,26)
        if r not in a:
            a[count] = r
            count += 1
    return(a)
print(f())
#8b
ls=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
def encrypt(alphabet):
    a=randomalpha()
    count=0
    b=input('enter a word')
    for i in b:               #not sure if i am ok up to here but this is when i got really confused 


print(encrypt(ls))
```

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete and/or really fuzzy. Please rewrite your question in a way so that everyone understands what exactly you are trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: so from the first code that I have which works, and returns a list of random non repeating integers... then i have the input ls in the next code which is an alphabet so say the first random list started [3,8,10... 3=a 8=b 10=c so if i then put in my input into the second code 'abc' it would return [3,8,10]

Comment: @KennyV does this help ? so from the first code that I have which works, and returns a list of random non repeating integers... then i have the input ls in the next code which is an alphabet so say the first random list started [3,8,10... 3=a 8=b 10=c so if i then put in my input into the second code 'abc' it would return [3,8,10]

Comment: What should happen if non-lowercase and/or non-alpha characters are encountered by `encrypt()`? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @martineau 3.2.3 we are supposed to only do this entering lowercase non numerical characters

Answer (score 2):

My take on it:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import shuffle

def char2num(chars):
    r = range(len(chars))
    shuffle(r)
    return dict(zip(chars, r))

def encrypt(s, lookup):
    return ' '.join(str(lookup[ch]) for ch in s)

print encrypt('cat', char2num(ascii_lowercase))
```

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND not quite (I posted the wrong version) - it's more generic - doesn't do some weird stuff with `.pop`, doesn't un-necessarily convert `alphabet` to a list, and uses a generator instead of a list-comp in the `.join`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string

def randomalpha():
    nums, result = range(26), [] # [0, 1, 2, 3, ... --> 25]
    random.shuffle(nums)
    for i in range(26):
        result.append(nums.pop())
    return result

def encrypt(s):
    alphabet = list(string.lowercase) # ['a', 'b', 'c', ... --> 'z']
    key = dict(zip(alphabet, randomalpha()))
    return ''.join([str(key[ltr]) for ltr in s])
```

References:

- [Dictionaries (`{'a': 1, 'b': 2, ... --> 'z': 26}`)](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [List Comprehensions (`\[elem for elem in iterable\]`)](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [`string.join(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`zip(*iterables)` (`zip(\['a', 'b', 'c'\], \[1, 2, 3\])` => `\[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)

Comment: Your `randomalpha` function will most likely produce duplicate values

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND u cannot get this to work, i got this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\lab8-1.py", line 146, in <module>
    print(encrypt())
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\lab8-1.py", line 143, in encrypt
    alphabet = list(string.lowercase)
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined

Comment: @IanBerke You have to do `import string` (copy my whole answer and try it).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here because of this question asked today: [Easiest way to assign a number to the alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811534/easiest-way-to-assign-a-number-to-the-alphabet)

```
 import random, string
    alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    numLst = list()
    while len(numLst) != 26:
        num = random.randint(1,26)
        if (num not in numLst):
            numLst.append(num)
```

Now all you have to do is index the lists to get the letter and corresponding unique random number. For instance alpha[0] gives you "a" and numLst[0] would give you corresponding unique number.