# Easiest way to assign a number to the alphabet?

Tags: python

I need to find the best way to assign each letter of the alphabet a random number 1-26 (using each number once). Or assign each number 1-26 a random letter of the alphabet (using each letter once).
For example:
a = 6, b = 12, c = 91
or
1 = g, 2 = a, 3 = k

I've tried assigning randint to each letter and repeating if the number has been used already but its really long.

Comment: What's really long? The code? You haven't shared any code so it's going to be hard for us to help you improve it. Please share.

Comment: You could use `random.choice` with `pop`.

Comment: or `random.shuffle`

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like this?

```
import random
x=['A','B','C'.....]
y=list(range(1,27))
random.shuffle(y)

combo=list(zip(x,y))
```

you could of course make the final output a dict or something